# Android GPUImageView upside down

Tags: android, image-processing, android-gpuimageview

I am using the [GPUImage library](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) for Android to do image processing. I have a main GPUImageView and a ListView (and RecyclerView) under it which shows the same image as in the main GPUImageView but with all the different filters. The image(s) in the ListView/RecyclerView are all flipped 180 degrees (upside down) and I have no idea why. I try to set the XML rotation (android:rotation="180") on the GPUImageView in XML but that results in a blank GPUImageView.
Here is my GPUImageView in XML:

```
      <jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageFilter"/>
```

Comment: are you sure that image is rotating? Did you found any solution for that?